# In Aurelia, what is the correct way to add temporary and dynamic elements

Tags: aurelia

I want to achieve an effect that I can have a view-model trigger the creation of one or more temporary elements in the DOM. These elements would be deleted after some period of time.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efunneko/bu2cwwta/5/) for a simple example of the effect I am after.

Here is a simple jQuery way of doing it:

```
var count = 1;
$("button").bind("click", function(e) {
    createNewNotifier(count++);
});

function createNewNotifier(text) {
    var div = $('<div></div>').appendTo(".notifications");
    div.text("Notification: " + text);
    div.hide(4000, function(){ $target.remove(); });
}
```

Comment: I'll say that I personally just use toastr to handle this situation. It "just works," even if it isn't an Aurelia component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just have an array of notifications that you publish notifications to -

```
export class Notifier {
  notifications = [];
  addNotification(notification) {
    this.notifications.push(notification);
    setTimeout(() => { 
      let index = this.notifications.indexOf(notification);
      notifications.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

in some view -

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="notification of notifier.notifications">${notification.value}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

and in your view-model

```
   import {Notifier} from './notifier';
   export class ViewModel {
     static inject = [Notifier];
     constructor(notifier) {
       this.notifier = notifier;
     }
     attached() {
       this.notifier.add({ value: 'Attached!' });
     }
   }
```

Comment: When the array changes, will all notifications be removed and readded? If so, would that affect ongoing animations?

Comment: If you assign a new array, that might happen, but if you are just using operations like `push`, `pop`, and `splice`  that operate on the array in place, then no, they won't be removed and readded.

Comment: After a bit of experimentation, I have found that it works as described as long as you use Aurelia 'enter' animations. It seems that if I a 'leave' animation, the template does not add a new notification element while the animation is running. A bug perhaps?